# Selenium Price Scraping for school final. Program opens but does not type in any information

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Python program running without errors but when the program opens Expedia it does not type anything in to the departure box. It goes to the box likes its supposed to but after a few seconds it clicks off and shuts the page down.

```
leaving_from = flight_info['Departure']
going_to = flight_info['Arrival']
trip_date = flight_info['Date']


#Go to Expedia
driver.get( "https://expedia.com")

#Click on Flights
#The flight_xpath represent the flight button on expedia
flight_xpath ="//a[@class='uitk-tab-anchor' and @aria-controls='search_form_product_selector_flights' and @role='tab' and @data-toggle='tab' and span[@class='uitk-tab-text' and text()='Flights']]"
flight_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, flight_xpath))
    )
flight_element.click()
time.sleep(0.2)

  #Click on One-Way. IBecause it is easier this way.
oneway_xpath = "//a[@class='uitk-tab-anchor' and @aria-controls='FlightSearchForm_ONE_WAY' and @aria-selected='false' and @role='tab' and @data-toggle='tab' and span[@class='uitk-tab-text' and text()='One-way']]"
one_way_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, oneway_xpath))
    )
one_way_element.click()
time.sleep(0.9)

#Part 1: Flying From, Flying To, Departure Date, Return Date

#**********************  Complete Leaving From Portion  **********************
leaving_from_xpath = "//button[@aria-label='Leaving from' and @data-stid='origin_select-dialog-trigger']"
leaving_from_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, leaving_from_xpath))
    )
leaving_from_element.clear
leaving_from_element.click()
time.sleep(1)
leaving_from_element.send_keys(leaving_from)

time.sleep(4) #Need this otherwise it will be too fast for the broswer
leaving_from_element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN)
#**********************  Complete Leaving From Portion  **********************
```

I tried to put a parenthesis around the `leaving_from_element.clear` but that made it so less opened up.